# laravel eloquent relationship getting property on non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database, one-to-many

This is the way I created my database (each employee can have multiple title) :

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

CREATE TABLE titles (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    title       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,title, from_date)
);
```

These are the corresponding models:

```
class employee extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no'; 
    public $incrementing = false; 
    protected $connection = 'testMYSQL';

    public function title()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\title', 'emp_no');
    }
}

class title extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = ['emp_no', 'title', 'from_date'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $connection = 'testMYSQL';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\employee', 'emp_no');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I used the models I'd created like this :

```
return $employee = employee::find(1)->title;
```

But I get this error for the line above:

> "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"

**Update**: These work fine though:

```
return $employee = employee::first()->title;
return $employee = title::first()->employee;
```

I think the relationships are correct and the problem is that Laravel still hasn't noticed that the primary key is **emp_no** and not **id**. I changed *$primaryKey* type from **protected** to **public** but still I get the same error.

Comment: There's no employee with `id` 1, so you're calling `->title` on null.

Comment: Do you have record with as `emp_no ==1`

Comment: Here the 'id' is 'emp_no', isn't it ? And an employee with 'emp_no' = 1 exists in my records

Comment: Yes it is, my mistake in the comment above. While this won't solve your current problem, eloquent models don't support composite primary keys, so the title model won't work the way you have it currently set up.

Comment: I think the error has something to do with the models. Have the relationships been defined correctly?

Comment: Run `\DB::enableQueryLog(); employee::find(1); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` and post the result.

Comment: array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `employees` where `employees`.`emp_no` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 4.16
  ]
]

Comment: As you see, Laravel is using `emp_no`. So there is no `employee` with that primary key in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think error of the find method because untill I know find() method only work on Id(primary key)

And your table has `emp_no` so,

```
employee::find(1)->title;
```

This method is not work and occurred the following errors

```
"Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"
```

Comment: But I have protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';  in my model.

Comment: Can you try with this 

$emp = employee::where('emp_no',1)->first();

$emp->title